# QuantumLeap: store the same model with different columns in two tables (timescale)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am using **NGSI-LD** and **Orion Context Broker** **v1.4**.

I need to store in two independent tables that start data from the same model but have different attributes.

If I use two subscriptions it stores them in the same table.

1 Subscription:

```json
{
    "description": "Store vehicle data",
    "type": "Subscription",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Vehicle"
        }
    ],
    "watchedAttributes": ["alternateName", "color", "license_plate", "name"],
    "notification": {
    "attributes": ["id", "alternateName", "color", "license_plate", "name"],
        "format": "normalized",
        "endpoint": {
            "uri": "{{qunatumleap}}:8668/v2/notify",
            "accept": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

2 Subscription:

```json
{
    "description": "Store dynamic data",
    "type": "Subscription",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Vehicle"
        }
    ],
    "watchedAttributes": ["location", "heading", "speed"],
    "notification": {
        "attributes": ["id","location", "heading", "speed"],
        "format": "normalized",
        "endpoint": {
            "uri": "{{quantumleap}}:8668/v2/notify",
            "accept": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively what you are asking to do here is to store Timescale data (via QuantumLeap) on to two separate tenants. For QuantumLeap 0.8.3, this was possible for NGSI-LD since QL 0.8.3 relied on the `fiware-service` header.  You could add a `receiverInfo` key into each subscription to split the data into separate tenants e.g. `tenant1`, `tenant2`

```json
"endpoint": {
  "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
  "accept": "application/json",
  "receiverInfo": [
    {
      "key": "fiware-service",
      "value": "tenant1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now with QuantumLeap 1.0, I think that the `NGSILD-Tenant` header is now properly supported, so this *"trick"* won't work directly, but you could relay the information via another microservice. e.g.:

```json
"endpoint": {
  "uri": "http://some-new-micro-service",
  "accept": "application/json",
  "receiverInfo": [
    {
      "key": "fiware-service",
      "value": "tenant1"
    }
  ]
}
```

All that the new-micro-service would need to do, would be to alter `NGSILD-Tenant` and combine it with the `fiware-service` header to come up with a new and unique tenant.

If you combine **Orion-LD** with **Mintaka** you could just use the NGSI-LD Temporal interface directly and make separate queries for the two types of data of course - for example using [this Grafana plugin](https://github.com/bfi-de/ngsild-grafana-datasource)